# Detect antivirus or firewall in Windows Server OS

Tags: c++, wmi, windows-server-2012-r2

In a normal Windows OS (client) , we can detect the presence of a firewall or antivirus software from the root/securitycenter2 using WMI.

But in Windows Server OS, there is no security center details.

As of now, I have used the registry to parse through the list of installed applications and checking if that has the name of an antivirus software to find out (not the best of methods to do this).

Is there any way to conclusively find out if the server system has a firewall or antivirus software installed and have been enabled?

Comment: For Server 16 there 's AMSI to scan with AV.

Comment: I need it mainly for the previous versions